# How can I outline my full website with a border in blue?

Tags: css

I'm looking for a CSS snippet to make full-screen outlined in blue to my website: D

Are you have a good idea of how I can do it?

Comment: Please, help us to help you - explain how to understand `full screen`. did you tried anything by yourself? Anything?

Answer (score 1):

This will do the job. It keeps the border in the viewport and there is a scrollbar if the content is to long. I explained the style in /* comment */

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Blue border</title>
<style>
/* viewport height must be 100% and remove ugly margin  */
html, body, #pagewrapper {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
/* keep borders and padding inside the elements */
body, body * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
/* hide horizontal and vertical overflow on the body */
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 4px solid blue;
}
/* give this div a scrollbar so you can scroll downwards */
#pagewrapper {
  overflow-y: scroll !important;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="pagewrapper">

<h3>Long text to see if it works</h3>
<p>abc<br>def<br>xyz<br>abc<br>def<br>xyz<br>abc<br>def<br>xyz<br>
abc<br>def<br>xyz<br>abc<br>def<br>xyz<br>abc<br>def<br>xyz<br>
abc<br>def<br>xyz<br>abc<br>def<br>xyz<br>abc<br>def<br>xyz<br>
abc<br>def<br>xyz<br>abc<br>def<br>xyz<br>abc<br>def<br>xyz<br>
abc<br>def<br>xyz<br>abc<br>def<br>xyz<br>abc<br>def<br>xyz<br>
abc<br>def<br>xyz<br>abc<br>def<br>xyz<br>abc<br>def<br>xyz<br>
abc<br>def<br>xyz<br>abc<br>def<br>xyz<br>abc<br>def<br>xyz</p>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try wrap html body tag

body {

border: blue

}

Comment: Always give the border-width and border-style, otherwise it will not show the border

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this. This will add a 5px width border. Change as required

**CSS CODE**

`body{border:5px solid blue;}`

Comment: This will not work if the  height of the content is greater then the height of the viewport (this is the area you can see in the browser)

Answer (score 0):

You can add this in you global css file:

```css
html *
{
    outline: 2px solid blue;
}
```